# Eigen dynamic matrix initialization

Tags: eigen

I am having some trouble figuring out how to set the rows and columns of a MatrixXd at runtime in Eigen. Can anyone point me to some documentation or give some pointer on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: have you read the documentation: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__DenseMatrixManipulation__chapter.html. in particular the following pages: the Matrix class, Block operations, and advanced initialization?

Comment: Yes i did. From what i could see all the code snippets seem to mention some variables for setting up MatrixXd. I figured this out though... i just declare a variable MatrixXd without specifying any rows or columns and at the point where the size is known just use setZero() with the known size.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define a MatrixXd size at runtime by using the method `resize(nrow, ncol)`. You can read more about resizing a dynamic matrix in [this link](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html) and its API definition [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#afbbb33d14fe7fb9683019a39ce1c659d).