# How to Define an Eigen Matrix size based upon a variable passed to a function

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to write code that needs to define a matrix size based upon an input. A stripped down version of the code that shows the issue is:

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include "eigen/Eigen/Dense"
    #include <cmath>

    using namespace Eigen;

    void matrixname(  const int numbRow, const int numbcol);

    int main()
    {
    const int numbRow=5;
    const int numbCol=3;

    matrixname(numbRow,numbCol);
    return 0;
    }

    void matrixname(  const int numbRow, const int  numbCol)
    {
    Matrix<double,numbRow,numbCol> y;
    }
```

When attempting to compile the code, the following error is returned:

/main.cpp:20:15: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression

The build breaks in the last line of trying to define y.

Is there any way I can modify the declaration or passing of the variables in order to be able to define the size of the matrix in this way?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html), if you don't know the size of a matrix at compile time you need to use the matrix size template parameters as `Eigen::Dynamic`.

So you may have to modify your function as follows:

```
void matrixname(  const int numbRow, const int  numbCol)
{
    Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic> y1(numbRow, numbCol);

    // Eigen also provides a typedef for this type
    MatrixXd y2(numbRow, numbCol);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: If this answered  your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick mark on the left!